# Copy columns without overwriting

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 different excel sheets, called: wsOrigin1 , wsOrigin2, wsDestiny. I use this code to locate and copy entire columns of wsOrigin1 and wsOrigin2 in wsDestiny, which is in the first row of wsOrigin1 and wsOrigin2, the column that says "here", and copy the column wsOrigin1 under the column that found wsOrigin2 in wsDestiny sheet, but the problem that I have is that the code I did to do this, this over writing the column you copied me wsOrigin2 on which wsOrigin1 copy first. this is the code I use:

```
  For c = 1 To 13
      If wsOrigin1.Cells(1, c).Value = "here" Then
         For cc = cc + 1 To 13
         ' fila , columna

            With wsOrigin1.Columns(c).CurrentRegion
          wsDestiny.Columns(cc).End(xlDown) _
          .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count).End(xlDown) = .Columns(c).Value
       End With

          Exit For
          Next cc
     End If
   Next c


   For c2 = 1 To 13
      If wsOrigin2.Cells(1, c2).Value = "here" Then
         For cc2 = cc2 + 1 To 13
         ' fila , columna

            With wsOrigin2.Columns(c2).CurrentRegion
         wsDestiny.Columns(cc2).End(xlUp) _
          .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count) = .Columns(c2).End(xlUp).Value
       End With

          Exit For
          Next cc2
     End If
   Next c2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For c = 1 To 13
      If wsOrigin1.Cells(1, c).Value = "here" Then
         For cc = cc + 1 To 13

           With wsOrigin1.Columns(c).CurrentRegion
           wsDestiny.Cells(Rows.Count, cc).End(xlUp) _
           .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count) = .Columns(c).Value
           End With

           Exit For
          Next cc
     End If
   Next c


For c2 = 1 To 13
     If wsOrigin2.Cells(1, c2).Value = "here" Then
      For cc2 = cc2 + 1 To 13

       With wsOrigin2.Columns(c2).CurrentRegion
         wsDestiny.Cells(Rows.Count, cc2).End(xlUp) _
          .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count) = .Columns(c2).Value
         End With

         Exit For
        Next cc2
   End If
 Next c2
```

Example results:

```
wsOrigin1:

   A    B    C  
1 here      here   
2 bla  ble  bli
3 bla  ble  bli
4 bla  ble  bli

wsOrgin2:

   A
1 here
2 blo
3 blo
4 blo

Result
code compile

wsDestiny:

   A    B      
1 here here   
2 bla  bli
3 bla  bli
4 bla  bli
5 here
6 blo
7 blo
8 blo
```